# A binary search tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

```
class Student
{
    String name;
    int roll;
    int age;
    public Student(String n,int r,int a) {
        name=n;
        roll=r;
        age=a;
    }
    public String retname() {
        return name;
    }
    public int retroll() {
        return roll;
    }
    public int retage() {
        return age;
    }
    public void displaystudent() {
        System.out.print("Name : "+name+" Roll : "+roll+" Age : "+age+"\n");
    }
}

class Node
{
    Student s;
    Node lchild;
    Node rchild;
    public Node(String n,int r ,int a) {
        s=new Student(n,r,a);
    }
    public void displayNode() {
        s.displaystudent();
    }
}
class Tree
{
    public Node root;
    public void insert(String n,int r,int a) {
        Node newNode=new Node(n,r,a);
        if(root==null)
            root=newNode;
        else {
            Node current=root;
            Node parent;
            while(true) {
                parent=current;
                if(n.compareTo(current.s.retname())<0) {
                    current=current.lchild;
                    if(current==null)
                        parent.lchild=newNode;
                    return;
                } else {
                    current=current.rchild;
                    if(current==null)
                        parent.rchild=newNode;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void order() {
        inorder(root);
        preorder(root);
        postorder(root);
    }
    public void inorder(Node localroot) {
        if(localroot!=null) {
            inorder(localroot.lchild);
            localroot.displayNode();
            inorder(localroot.rchild);
        }
    }
    public void preorder(Node localroot) {

        if(localroot!=null) {
            preorder(localroot.lchild);
            preorder(localroot.rchild);
            localroot.displayNode();
        }
    }
    public void postorder(Node localroot) {
        if(localroot!=null) {
            localroot.displayNode();
            postorder(localroot.lchild);
            postorder(localroot.rchild);
        }
    }
}
class e
{
    public static void main(String [] args) { //throws IOException

        Tree t=new Tree();
        t.insert("E",1,23);
        t.insert("D",2,2);
        t.insert("C",3,4);
        t.insert("B",4,89);

        t.insert("A",5,45);

        t.order();
    }
}
```

The above code is not showing all the outputs that it should. Also, why is that the preorder and inorder gives the same result?
Also, how can the traversal be possible in a sub-tree not starting from root?
Is there any way to avoid recursion?

This is the current incorrect output. It should print all the elements that I have inserted and that too in a particular order.

```
Name : D Roll : 2 Age : 2 
Name : E Roll : 1 Age : 23 
Name : D Roll : 2 Age : 2 
Name : E Roll : 1 Age : 23 
Name : E Roll : 1 Age : 23 
Name : D Roll : 2 Age : 2
```

Comment: What outputs do you get and what do you expect it to show you?

Comment: @BradySheehan `Name : D Roll : 2 Age : 2
Name : E Roll : 1 Age : 23
Name : D Roll : 2 Age : 2
Name : E Roll : 1 Age : 23
Name : E Roll : 1 Age : 23
Name : D Roll : 2 Age : 2` This is the current output.It should print all the elements that I have inserted and that too in a particular order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious and first problem I noticed was in your `insert` method. In this method, you always return before checking the next iteration of the while loop (in the case that the root has sub children, nothing gets inserted). To fix this error, just change your while loop like this:

```
while(true)
     { 
        parent=current; //assign parent to root
        if(n.compareTo(current.s.retname())<0) 
        {
             current=current.lchild; 
             if(current==null) {//added brackets so the return only happened when this was true
               parent.lchild=newNode;
               return;
            }
       }
       else
       { 
        current=current.rchild;
        if(current==null){ //added brackets so the return only happened when this was true
            parent.rchild=newNode;
            return;
            }
        }
   }
```

After making these changes, your other questions may be answered on there own. Make these changes and see if it fixes your problems, if not comment to let me know and I'll take another look.

Edit one:

I think your preorder is wrong. I believe you should be printing the node *before* recursively traversing the left and right children respectively. It should look like this:

```
   public void preorder(Node localroot) {

    if(localroot!=null) {
        localroot.displayNode(); //here!
        preorder(localroot.lchild);
        preorder(localroot.rchild);
        //localroot.displayNode(); not here!
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked. you win sir! Also what about the last three questions?

Comment: Have you compared the output for in-order and pre-order after making the proposed changes?

Comment: Yes and surprisingly they are the same.

Comment: Did the preorder adjustment fix the problem with them being the same?

Comment: If preorder is to be fixed then so is the postorder,isn't it? I have changed bot pre and postorder and now they are not the same as obvious!